# How to pass images from server to function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, file, server, photos

I'm trying to pass images to function in JS that extracts metadata. Said images are kept in folder on server(localhost for now). I got the function to work with file input from HTML but have no idea how to pull the pictures from the server and pass them to the function.

Any ideas are appreciated. There is no need for ultrasonic speeds.

What I have is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="exif.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
Upload a local file to read Exif data.
<br/>
<input id="file-input" type="file"/>
<br/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("file-input").onchange = function (e) {
        EXIF.getData(e.target.files[0], function () {
            let lat = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLatitude');
            let long = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLongitude');
            let alt = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSAltitude');
            let toDecimalLat = lat[0].numerator + lat[1].numerator /
                    (60 * lat[1].denominator) + lat[2].numerator / (3600 * lat[2].denominator);
            let toDecimalLong = long[0].numerator + long[1].numerator /
                    (60 * long[1].denominator) + long[2].numerator / (3600 * long[2].denominator);
            let toDecimalAlt = alt.numerator / alt.denominator;
            console.log(toDecimalLat);
            console.log(toDecimalLong);
            console.log(toDecimalAlt);
            console.log(e.target.files[0]);
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Did what was suggested by PamBlam but it works only every second time triggered (button clicked).

This is the code:

```
<body>
Upload a local file to read Exif data.
<br/>
<button id="target">Click</button>
<br/>
<script>
    $("#target").click(function () {
        console.log("button clicked");
        var myImage = new Image();
        myImage.src = 'pictures/pic.jpg';
        EXIF.getData(myImage, function () {
            let lat = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLatitude');
            let long = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLongitude');
            let alt = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSAltitude');
            let toDecimalLat = lat[0].numerator + lat[1].numerator /
                    (60 * lat[1].denominator) + lat[2].numerator / (3600 * lat[2].denominator);
            let toDecimalLong = long[0].numerator + long[1].numerator /
                    (60 * long[1].denominator) + long[2].numerator / (3600 * long[2].denominator);
            let toDecimalAlt = alt.numerator / alt.denominator;
            console.log(toDecimalLat);
            console.log(toDecimalLong);
            console.log(toDecimalAlt);
            console.log(this);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The server does not "pass" anything to the browser, but rather the browser "pulls" the image from the server. And if the file is on the 'server' why are you using an file input field? You should just pull it from the server, the file input field is used to upload an image from the local machine to the browser, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: sounds like the relevant code would be the code that's sending it, not receiving it... anyway, `e.target` looks like you're pulling files from a file input, which has to do with files on the client machine, not images from the server... however, this information is easy to get from php or other server side languages.

Comment: No, I am trying to pull images from the server. I did try with ajax but didn't succeed, probably did something wrong.

Comment: Your sure its running on an actual server and not on `file://`

Comment: Absolutely, running on Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you have `e.tartget.files[0]`, replace it with an `Image`. You make the image like this:

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png';
```

So you would replace `e.tartget.files[0]` with `myImage`. Then obviously change the url to the file.. ie http://localhost/pics/image.jpg

---

If you're having problems with it working intermittently, you may have a race condition. Solve it by throwing your logic in the `onload` function...

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png';
myImage.onload = function(){ 
    EXIF.getData(myImage, function (){
        // exif stuff here...
    }
};
```

Comment: That was totally what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BiserAtanasov - if that solved your problem, please hit the checkmark by the answer..

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you! Added some other small issue in the main post.